# Which is the use of transform?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, statistics

Doing the module 7 in Datacamp it ask me to do `mean()`, `median()` and `std()` in different columns with certain specifications, such as the price `std()` for different airlines.

I have created this `.csv` with ChatGPT to ilustrate an example. Calling this `.csv` file `planes.csv`, which is:

```
Airline,Price
Delta,350
United,420
American Airlines,380
Delta,320
Southwest,250
United,400
American Airlines,410
Delta,300
Southwest,280
United,390
American Airlines,430
```

which is the difference between the first and the second? Why does the second return an **empty** list?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# This is correct
planes["airline_price_st_dev"] = planes.groupby("Airline")\
                                            ["Price"].transform(lambda x: x.std())

print(planes[["Airline", "airline_price_st_dev"]].value_counts())

# This is not correct
planes["airline_price_st_dev"] = planes.groupby("Airline")\
                                            ["Price"].std()

print(planes[["Airline", "airline_price_st_dev"]].value_counts())
```

Answer (score 0):

fellow DataCamp learner here!

The `transform` applies the operation (`std()`) elementwise. The output with and without `transform` therefore has different shape

```
print(planes.groupby("Airline")["Price"].transform(lambda x: x.std()).shape)

# output is (N,) where N is the no. of observations in your dataframe

print(planes["airline_price_st_dev"] = planes.groupby("Airline")["Price"].std().shape)
# output is (K,) where K is the no. of different Airlines
```

After assigning the latter as a new column, that new column has only null values as the shape of the latter is appropriate to match into the dataframe